# iOS:XMPP: Typing indication not working with Different client

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am starting to develop one XMPP ios client using **robbiehanson/XMPPFramework**  I tried to achieve *user is tying..*  ie Typing indicator. It is working when both the users are using ios client. When I tried to use multiple client ie one user is using iOS client and another user using Spark desktop clien, the typing indicator is not working.

//Send Typing notification

```
NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:self.userprofile.jidStr];

// [message addChild:body];

// chat notifications
XMPPMessage *xmppMessage = [XMPPMessage messageFromElement:message];



[xmppMessage addComposingChatState];

[appDelegate.xmppStream sendElement:xmppMessage];
```

// For Receive Typing Notification

```
 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
    {
    if ([message hasComposingChatState]) {
            self.statusLabel.text=@"is typing...";
        }
    }
```

The Typing notification is working fine when both users using my iOS client. **But when one using ios client and another user using different client, the Typing notification is not working**,

Please provide me the best way to achieve this.

Comment: The other can be that Spark desktop client is not coded with 'is typing' feature.

Answer (score 0):

Replace following line

```
[xmppMessage addComposingChatState];
```

with

```
[xmppMessage addMarkableChatMarker];
```

Other code is fine. Try this.

Comment: Thanks, is this code for sending typing notification from ios client to other clients. How about receiving typing notifcation from other client?

Comment: from other side as you have coded `hasComposingChatState` will work

Comment: if the user sends message from different client, didReceiveMessage called only once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement xmpp-0022 , in this way messaging apps implements typing, sent, delivered and seen status

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0022.html#sect-idp643808